# How can I specify an email address in the SLURM snakemake json configuration file?

Tags: snakemake, slurm

I am working on a SLURM-based cluster. I am currently using the following slurm json file:

```
{
    "__default__" :
    {
        "A" : "overall",
        "time" : "96:00:00",
        "nodes": 1,
        "ntasks": 1,
        "cpus" : 24,
        "p" : "LONG",
        "mem": 16G,
        "output": "snakemake%A.out",
        "error": "snakemake%A.err"
    }
}
```

along with the following command:

```
snakemake --jobs 200 --use-conda --printshellcmds  --cluster-config slurm.json --cluster "sbatch -A {cluster.A} -p {cluster.p} -t {cluster.time} --output {cluster.output} --error {cluster.error} --ntasks {cluster.ntasks} --cpus-per-task {cluster.cpus} --mem {cluster.mem}"
```

I would like to be able to specify my email and receive an email when a job finishes. I have tried adding a line in the json file with `"email": my@email.com` and an option to the sbatch command `--email {cluster.email}` but that did not work.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: After looking at some headers of files (`#SBATCH --mail-user=email@com`I have used `--mail-user` instead. I'll let you know if I receive an email.

Comment: I'd be surprised if [--mail-user](https://github.com/dpryan79/Misc/blob/master/MPIIE_internal/SlurmEasy#L85-L90) didn't end up working. Note also `--mail-type`.

Comment: so --mail-user on its own didn't work but by adding the --mail-type, it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by the comments and the SLURM manual (not so much bioinformatics related?)

You need the following terms in your batch/queuing command:

```
--mail-type=ALL
--mail-user=you@email.com
```

I used "ALL" which will send you *all* reports. If you just want the finish message then you would use "END" and "FAIL" like such:

```
--mail-type=END,FAIL
```

Here are the specifics from the [manual](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) if you wish to make a different selection:

**--mail-type=**

> Notify user by email when certain event types occur. Valid type values
>   are NONE, BEGIN, END, FAIL, REQUEUE, ALL (equivalent to BEGIN, END,
>   FAIL, REQUEUE, and STAGE_OUT), STAGE_OUT (burst buffer stage out and
>   teardown completed), TIME_LIMIT, TIME_LIMIT_90 (reached 90 percent of
>   time limit), TIME_LIMIT_80 (reached 80 percent of time limit),
>   TIME_LIMIT_50 (reached 50 percent of time limit) and ARRAY_TASKS (send
>   emails for each array task). Multiple type values may be specified in
>   a comma separated list. The user to be notified is indicated with
>   --mail-user. Unless the ARRAY_TASKS option is specified, mail notifications on job BEGIN, END and FAIL apply to a job array as a
>   whole rather than generating individual email messages for each task
>   in the job array.

**--mail-user=**

> User to receive email notification of state changes as defined by
>   --mail-type. The default value is the submitting user.